# Greenplum database demo cluster scripts are not working

Tags: database, greenplum

I have been trying to build and test the code for greenplum open source project as per steps given at [site](https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb). 
I could build the code. However there is a section “Basic GPDB source configuration, compilation, gpdemo cluster creation and test execution example”.  So to test demo cluster, I am facing an issue.  Can someone please look at it and help me to know what is missing?

In short , steps followed are :

```
Cd /root/greenplum/gpdb-master/

./configure --prefix=/root/greenplum/gpdb-master

make

make install

source /root/greenplum/gpdb-master/greenplum_path.sh

cd gpAux/gpdemo

make cluster
```

As of now, I am stuck on “make cluster” step.  It shows error as :

> Optimizer state .. : ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "optimizer"

The complete log for Make cluster command is as follows :

```
[root@ vm gpdemo]# make cluster
```

This is a demo of the Greenplum Database system.  We will create
a cluster installation with master and 6 segment instances
(3 primary & 3 mirror).

```
GPHOME ................. : /root/greenplum/gpdb-master
MASTER_DATA_DIRECTORY .. : /root/greenplum/gpdb-master/gpAux/gpdemo/datadirs/qddir/demoDataDir-1

MASTER PORT (PGPORT) ... : 15432
SEGMENT PORTS .......... : 25432 25433 25434 25435 25436 25437 25438 25439 25440 25441 25442 25443
```

NOTE(s):

```
* The DB ports identified above must be available for use.
* An environment file gpdemo-env.sh has been created for your use.
executing:
/root/greenplum/gpdb-master/bin/gpinitsystem -a -c clusterConfigFile ""
20151214:18:30:22:027540 gpinitsystem:root-[WARN]:-No initdb file, unable to verify id
20151214:18:30:22:027540 gpinitsystem:root-[INFO]:-Checking configuration parameters, please wait...
20151214:18:30:22:gpinitsystem:root-[FATAL]:-Unable to run this script as root Script Exiting!

========================================
gpinitsystem returned: 2
========================================

                          OPTIMIZER STATE

----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Optimizer state .. : ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "optimizer"

======================================================================
PostgreSQL 8.4.20 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4), 64-bit
(1 row)

======================================================================
    make: [cluster] Error 2 (ignored)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't run this as root. There is no need to be root, and there is a FATAL error telling you exactly that you should avoid this.

Comment: Thanks, it was problem because of root user.

Comment: i tride to build the greenplum too, but it stucked at 5% 
    Building CXX object libgpos/CMakeFiles/gpos.dir/src/memory/CMemoryVisitorPrint.cpp.o, any idea?

Comment: @jemsnaban Can you please not hijack old and unrelated threads, but rather create a new posting? Thanks.